# How to improve performance of JPA batch inserts when using Spring Security and Auditing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, audit

Due to the `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotation, the custom `AuditorAware` class is being called to `getCurrentAuditor()` in order to populate the audit fields `lastCreatedBy` and `lastModifiedBy`.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<User> {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Optional<User> getCurrentAuditor() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return Optional.of(authentication)
                .map(Authentication::getName)
                .flatMap(userRepository::findByUsername);
    }
}
```

This class needs to call a repository in order to get that information (extracting the username / principal from the security context and fetching a user).

This works fine in the context of saving one entity at a time, but when doing batch inserts using `saveAll()`, the operation turns into a loop in order to call `getCurrentAuditor()` for every entity/row.

What's the best way to have performant batch inserts while also having Audit data? In my case I'm dealing with a bulk import from the same user, so all the records will have the same audit values.

Comment: why do you need to do a user lookup in the database and not just get the user from the principal `return ((MyUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUser();`

Comment: @Toerktumlare Because the auth token is issued by a 3rd party (Auth0), and it only contains the username of the user and some Auth0 ID. I need to fetch the user from the DB using that information. 

Besides, even if I could extract the `User` from the `Principal` as suggested, the issue remains that `saveAll()` would turn into a loop instead of a batch save (single operation) because of this `AuditorAwareImpl `

Comment: then you need to include that information in your question

Comment: I gave a possible solution. If you are using Auth in order to retrieve token, maybe you are using spring security resource server and you can enrich the spring Authentication Object by inserting the whole info about the logged user and avoid queries in the AuditorAwareImpl

Comment: fetch the user data and store the user data in thread local. Use it when you need to do your batch update, in the next batch update, check if there is data in thread local, if there is, use that data.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issue, I remember eventually we used second level cache to increase performance, also you can cache the result of this method `findByUsername`

Take a look at these samples:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

https://medium.com/@himani.prasad016/caching-in-hibernate-3ad4f479fcc0

`saveAll()` in Spring just calls `save()` under the hood

```
public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {

    Assert.notNull(entities, "Entities must not be null");

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are using spring security resource server so you may use custom claim converter
In my project I used the following configuration

```
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(exchanges ->
                    exchanges
                            .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**",
                                    "/v3/api-docs.yaml",
                                    "/swagger-ui/**",
                                    "/swagger-ui.html")
                                .permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/protected/**")
                                .authenticated())
            .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> {
                httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable();
            })
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(jwtConfigurer -> {
                jwtConfigurer.decoder(jwtDecoder());
            }))
            .headers(headerSpec -> {
                headerSpec.contentSecurityPolicy(contentSecurityPolicySpec -> {
                    contentSecurityPolicySpec.policyDirectives(
                                    "script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-rAnd0m123' 'unsafe-inline' http: https:;" +
                                    "default-src 'self'; "+
                                    "object-src 'none';" +
                                    "base-uri 'none';" +
                                    "require-trusted-types-for 'script';"
                    );
                }).xssProtection(xssProtectionSpec -> {
                    /*According to this https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/headers.html#headers-xss-protection
                     and this https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/HTTP_Headers_Cheat_Sheet.html#x-xss-protection
                     we need to disable X-XSS-Protection and give precedence to CSP https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/HTTP_Headers_Cheat_Sheet.html#content-security-policy-csp
                     */
                    xssProtectionSpec.headerValue(XXssProtectionHeaderWriter.HeaderValue.DISABLED);
                });
            })
            .build();
}

@Bean

public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

// @Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    try {
        NimbusJwtDecoder decoder = JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(env.getProperty("issuer-uri"));
        decoder.setClaimSetConverter(new OauthSubClaimAdapter());
        return decoder;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Impossibile proseguire. Avvenuto errore nella creazione del jwtDecoder",
                e);
    }
}
```

While my OauthSubClaimAdapter is:

```
public class OauthSubClaimAdapter implements Converter<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>> {

  public static final String LOGGED_USER_INFO = "loggedUserInfo";
  private final MappedJwtClaimSetConverter delegate = MappedJwtClaimSetConverter.withDefaults(
      Collections.emptyMap());

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> convert(Map<String, Object> claims) {
    Map<String, Object> convertedClaims = this.delegate.convert(claims);
    if (null == convertedClaims) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
          String.format("Impossible continue; no converted claim found in %s",
              getClass().getName()));
    }
    String username = (String) convertedClaims.get("sub");
    //Here you can put your logic in order to enrich the user recovered from the JWT token
    convertedClaims.put(LOGGED_USER_INFO, enrichedUser);
    return convertedClaims;
  }
}
```

And in your Authentication Object now you can retrieve all JWT claims containing also the LOGGED_USER_INFO object

Comment: as i pointed out in another comment, this scales extremely bad as you have to do a database call on each and every JWT that gets sent to the service even though maybe no batch updates might be needed.

Comment: @Toerktumlare it depends on the use case. According to the provided info the scenario should be this one: the user need to "enrich" the logged user by adding some info not present in the JWT token but inside the application DB. I think this is the best place where to put this enrichment and where to use both JPA 2nd level cache and maybe some other cache like Redis

Comment: The use case is defined but the technical demands of the solution is not, but the code you have supplied has the exact problems i pointed out and i stick by it. It does not matter ”where you place it” this code needs to do one database call for each request that provides a token. That does not scale well. Then he might as well do a db lookup for each audit entry. Thats what he wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `CustomAuthenticationConverter` (extends `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`)

to transform the JWT token into a

`CustomAuthenticationToken` (extends `org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken`)

In this converter you can put the `User` information from the database into the `CustomAuthenticationToken.details` field.

This `CustomAuthenticationToken` will be accessible via:

`(CustomAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`

You can register your custom converter in the `SecurityFilterChain` configuration.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, CustomAuthenticationToken> {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public CustomAuthenticationToken convert(final Jwt jwt) {
        //TODO: Convert JWT to Authentication object.
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        CustomAuthenticationToken authentication = new CustomAuthenticationToken();
        authentication.setDetails(user);
        return authentication;
    }
}

@Component
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<User> {

    @Override
    public Optional<User> getCurrentAuditor() {
        CustomAuthenticationToken authentication = (CustomAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return Optional.of(authentication)
                .map(Authentication::getDetails)
                .map(User.class::cast);
    }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        ...

        httpSecurity
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new CustomAuthenticationConverter(userRepository));
        return httpSecurity.build();

    }
}
```

This way you don't need to call database all the time because `User` information is available in the `SecurityContext`.

Comment: this will have extremely bad performance and wont scale as you have to do a database request on every single JWT that gets sent to the server.

Comment: An alternative solution is not mapping the `User` entity and storing directly the `username` contained in the token in the audited entity fields, but this field should be the foreign key to the `User` entity; then no database query is required.

Comment: There is no performance or scaling issues with this, it's a tested solution. Retrieving user information is part of the authentication process. If the User entity is mapped to the audit fields at least one database query is required to audit the entities, in this case the query is per JWT and not per "repository save" operation.

Comment: ”Tested” has nothing to do with performance, and databases do not scale well. That is a known fact, if i do 2000 requests a second to this application. The database will be the bottleneck. The purpose of using a jwt is to minimize additional requests and database calls. So no, this will not scale well. The converter is added to the decoder, which means it will get applied on each provided jwt during the authorization process since in his case the token is generated during authentication in the external issuer (okta).

Comment: "The purpose of using a jwt is to minimize additional requests and database calls". However most of the regular request will call the database multiple times, in fact this is the case, so it's not decisive in the application performance. Maybe in another context is valid, but not in this case for sure...
Remember: _Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil_

Comment: Your argument does not hold up since what the asker wanted was a more efficient way than doing one db call per audit line. All you did was move the database call so that there is one db call on each and every request which i know for a fact will bring a lot of overhead. Just because its easier to craft square car wheels than round doesnt mean i have to craft them first and try them out before switching to round wheel. Some things come with experience. Build it yourself and loadtest it, the db will be your bottleneck. You are even doing one dbcall even when there might not be any audit insert

Answer (score 0):

I think you can minimizes the repetitive database calls by fetching the auditor once at the start of the batch operation and reusing it for all entities in the batch, thereby improving performance.

First, create a cache to store the auditor:

```
@Service public class AuditorCache {
  private User cachedAuditor;

  public void cacheAuditor(User auditor) {
     this.cachedAuditor = auditor;
   }

   public Optional<User> getCachedAuditor() {
     return Optional.ofNullable(cachedAuditor);
   }

    public void clearCache() {
      cachedAuditor = null;
    }
}
```

Then, modify your AuditorAwareImpl to use this cache:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<User> {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final AuditorCache auditorCache;

    @Override
    public Optional<User> getCurrentAuditor() {
        return auditorCache.getCachedAuditor()
                .or(() -> {
                    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                    return Optional.ofNullable(authentication)
                            .map(Authentication::getName)
                            .flatMap(userRepository::findByUsername)
                            .map(user -> {
                                auditorCache.cacheAuditor(user);
                                return user;
                            });
                });
    }
}
```

Finally, manage the cache during your batch operation:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BatchService {

    private final AuditorCache auditorCache;
    private final YourEntityService yourEntityService;

    public void performBatchOperation(List<YourEntity> entities) {
        try {
            // Retrieve and cache auditor before batch operation
            auditorCache.cacheAuditor(retrieveAuditorForBatch());

            // Perform batch operation
            yourEntityService.saveAll(entities);
        } finally {
            // Clear cache after operation
            auditorCache.clearCache();
        }
    }

    private User retrieveAuditorForBatch() {
        // Logic to retrieve the auditor for the batch operation
    }
}
```

Comment: Services are singletons per default, in a threaded environment you might get race conditions with this solution, if 2 threads are doing batch updates at the same time.

Comment: a simpler solution would be to check if the user data is in local storage, if not, fetch the data and then use it and store it in thread local. Next run, you check if there is data in thread local, if there is, use it, when done, clear thread local.

Comment: or you need to add the `@RequestScope` annotation to your bean

Comment: Agreed, this does not look thread safe

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is not mapping the `User` entity and storing directly the `username` contained in the token in the audited entity fields, but this field should be the foreign key to the `User` entity; then no database query is required.